# How can I implement keyboard navigation in a Vuetify v-data-table?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

Vuetify team is still working on it ([here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9164) you can find the open issue), but I really need this feature. Do you know any workaround?

**Edit #1**

The idea behind this workaround is to [tab through checkboxes](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9164#issuecomment-686532611) and take andvantage of `@focus` event.

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-data-table
      class="elevation-1"
      v-model="selectedItem"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"
      height="750"
      fixed-header
      show-select
      single-select
      disable-pagination
    >
      <!-- v-simple-checkbox are not focusable, that's why we replace them -->
      <template #item.data-table-select="{ isSelected, select }">
        <!-- Might be misaligned, add CSS if needed -->
        <v-checkbox
          :value="isSelected"
          hide-details
          @focus="select(!isSelected)"
          @change="select(!isSelected)"
        ></v-checkbox>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

While this solution kinda works, there are a couple of things to point out:

1. We won't be able to navigate by using arrow keys.
2. You must add `show-select` and `single-select` to your table.
3. Sometimes focus jumps around. For example, If I tab to **item 7** and then click on **item 3**, next time I'll use tab **item 8** will be selected instead of **item 4**.

If you are looking for a workaround this approach might suit you, but if you are looking for a solution I suppose we must wait for Vuetify 3.

Comment: You can add `@focus` handler to each checkbox which will set the state to "checked".

Comment: @IVOGELOV could you provide a working code snippet?

Comment: Sure, but it must be based on your code that you claim is not currently working.

Comment: @IVOGELOV If you are still interested, I edited my question.